# Order of JSON important while sending data?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, api, post

I have a post API where I am sending JSON data.

```
{   
    "timestamp": 1592977899880,
    "userid": 123
}
```

this works fine but when I change the order

```
{   
    "userid": 123,
    "timestamp": 1592977899880    
}
```

I get null in API
Note:- timestamp field is int and I am sending 13 digits long in the timestamp. But why is it working in the first scenario

```
    public HttpResponseMessage dataSync(AnalyticsData request)
```

This is where I am expecting the JSON
For the first scenario in request field, I am getting
request.userid = 123 and
request.timestamp = 0
while for the second case, I am getting
request = null

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage dataSync(AnalyticsData request)
    {
         if(request != null)
         { //..some stuff
         }
    }

    public class AnalyticsData
    {
        public int timestamp { get; set; }
        public int userid { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: the first example that "works" isn't valid JSON - the commas are all wrong; are you sure you have the "works" and "doesn't work" examples the right way around? this *could* also be tied into an overflow problem masking things, so maybe try changing your timestamp to `long` while you're there

Comment: To be explicit: no, the order in JSON doesn't usually matter to any reasonable serializer, and asp.net-mvc uses a fairly reasonable serializer. As for why it isn't working in this case: you have at least 2 known problems (the commas, and the overflow); I'd start by fixing those!

Comment: yes it is true @MarcGravell order of JSON doesn't matter and also I have changed the variable to long. But I am trying to figure out why for the first case it mapped with the variables even if it exceeds the int limit

Comment: Your [mcve] will include the source code for `AnalyticsData`.

Comment: hey, @mjwills example added

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling `dataSync`?

Comment: calling through postman

Answer (score 0):

When you send a parameter in an API call , this should be as it the API ''expects'' , as it shows in your API documentation.

So the first one it is in the format that the API expects and the second one is in wrong format , by this I mean that maybe the API needs first the TimeStamp parameter and second the UserId. This is why this happened.

In addition in your question you have format wrong the first JSON , the comma should be  after the first parameter , not after the last one.

Comment: @mjwills, of course it is a wrong JSON , I know that, this why I have edit the question , but the edit it is still pending, Aso I edit my answer in order to be clear what I mean

Comment: I've rejected the proposed edit, specifically because I don't think we should fix the JSON unless we know whether the broken JSON is *part of the problem being observed*

Comment: as for the other part: I'm not aware of any mainstream JSON serializer that is fussy about order

Answer (score -2):

It all depends on how the API handles the incoming data. In some cases, for example .NET Core, it may try to automatically map JSON to a c# class in which case the order may not matter as much, as long as the names of the fields match the properties of the class. In other cases it may treat JSON as a raw string, and then manually build an object off of it, in which case it may expect certain things to be in certain order, format, datatype, etc.